# Closing the previous activities except for some of them in Java

Tags: java, android

When I open an activity, I want to close the other activities except for the main activity. I have searched this issue on the internet and I found these codes but they don't work properly for my purpose. Because I don't want to add the same code in every button and I don't want to close all the activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Activity06.this, Activity14.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Actually, I want to add the code in `onCreate` methods of each activity, not in the `onClick` methods of the buttons. If you have any solution, please answer this question and let me know.

Comment: Can you explain more about your situation? It sounds like you're saying every time you open any Activity, you want to close all other Activities - why would you want that? And have you considered using Fragments instead?

Comment: I'm new in Android programming and I'm still at the beginning of the learning. Thank you to let me know about fragments. I will search for it more. If it solves my problem I will delete this question from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all new activities to be closed once new activity is started from them you should call **this.finish()** after this line **startActivity(intent);**
And don't call finish method after start activity line from main activity. You main activity will not be closed but call finish from all other activities so they get finished after starting new activities.

Comment: That's a good solution. However, in each activity, I have 7 activity navigation buttons. That's why I don't want to add the same code in each activity navigation button and make the code longer and longer. Instead of it, can I do something like that in `onCreate` method of each activity?

Comment: you just need one line for each navigation.
                                
            '
                 // If you want all 7 new activities  to be closed if they start another from 
                   them.
                //  From all 7 activities when you call start activity, add a line as below.
              this.finish()'

Comment: or just do it like create a method  'void startNewactivity(Activity next,Bundle extras){
//create new intent here put next.class in it and start activity }'
Use this method for all navigation

Comment: On the internet, I have searched more; however, I couldn't find a better solution to solve this problem. Thank you for your interest, I will use this technique in my application for each navigation button.